# How to get the value of the key present inside an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is my sample data from which I want to extract the string present inside ResponseVariations array's object : CriterionExpression

```
Articles":[
"ResponseVariations":[
"CriterionExpression":"User: internal AND Country: CA"
]
]

Code Snippet:
function getChannel(agent){
const channelInfo = agent.Articles;
channelInfo.forEach((ResponseVariations) => {
          if(channelInfo.values(CriterionExpression)!=="DEFAULT_SELECTION")
          var iterator = channelInfo.values();
         console.log(iterator.next().value);
});
```

But the above criteria is not fitting well to extract information of those criteria in which the String is not DEFAULT_SELECTION.
Any suggestions how to traverse this array object's value ?

Comment: You say you have an array, yet I see the values being associated with identifiers (keys) _and_ your code accesses them as properties via their identifiers. Is it an array as you say, or an object as the example currently suggests?

Comment: Yes it has the identifiers (ResponseVariations) like a key inside the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked in order to fetch the key:

```
const _dir1 = path.resolve(__dirname, `../`);
    const _config1 = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(_dir, "./export.4862052732962492282_2.json"), "utf-8"));
    const filteredArr = {};

    _config1.Articles.forEach(el => {
    if (el.ResponseVariations && el.ResponseVariations.length > 1 ) {
    el.ResponseVariations && el.ResponseVariations.forEach((rv) => {
      if(rv.CriterionExpression !== 'DEFAULT_SELECTION') {
      console.log('not default', rv);
      filteredArr[rv.CriterionExpression]= rv.Text;
      project['data']['supportedChannels'].push(filteredArr);
      }
    })
```